# youtube related video and on Pause more videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Dears,
is there anyway to disable the related videos sent by youtube API through any player, as i am using WordPress and h5p for built LMS courses.

i am trying to disable the related videos at the end in the video and also there is more videos when you Pause the video.

hope the disable this as this is LMS and learning portal for users and they are confusing a lot from this videos.

best regards,

Answer (score 0):

H5P needs to use [YouTube's API for iframe embeds](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). That API does not provide an option to disable the related videos, and given that the API uses an iframe to provide the videos, there's no way to modify the video appearance. Guess you cannot get free video hosting and full control at the same time.